# Outside her control

Tags: grammar, prepositions

The following excerpt is from an article about a film director from the *Washington Post*, written by Amy Nicholson:

> Overnight, she became a major Hollywood contender, but then she fought, and lost, two bruising rounds against the studio system when her big-budget follow-ups flopped for reasons **outside her control**.

Should it be "outside OF her control"?
Although omitting the 'of' sounds OK in a speech form.
Is this an exception to grammar rule that I don't know? Or just a stylistic choice?

If I were the writer, I would have included the 'of' which is not wrong, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Outside" is fine. "Outside of" is more commonly used in American English than in British, where "outside" usually suffices, but, like its cousin "off of", it is colloquial and not recommended for formal writing.